# Show that the set forms a monotone class.

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to solve the following exercise .

> Let $(\Omega,\Im)$ be a Boolean measurable space where $\Im$ is an algebra.Let $A_n$ forms a partition of $\Omega$ i.e. $A_n \neq \emptyset$ and $\Omega =\bigcup A_n$ Show that the following set $S$ is a monotone class.$$S=\{\bigcup_n B_n \mid B_n \in \sigma(\Im\vert_{A_n})\}$$

It is clear that the $S$ is closed under increasing limit.But since union and intersection do not commute in general i am having problem in proving that $S$ is closed under decreasing limit.Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you can compute Boolean operations on each $A_n$ separately, since they are disjoint.  So for instance, if you have sets $C^m=\bigcup_n B^m_n$ in $S$ with $B^m_n\in\sigma(\mathfrak{F}|_{A_n})$, then $\bigcap_m C^m$ is just $\bigcup_n B_n$ where $B_n=\bigcap_m B^m_n$.  (In fact, in this manner it is just as easy to show that $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra as it is to show that $S$ is a monotone class.)

Comment: I think i dont follow completely.Could you please explain little more why these union and intersection commute ?(For showing $\sigma-$ algebra the problem is in showing that $S$ is closed under complement)

Comment: Take an element $x\in\bigcap_m C^m$.  Then $x\in A_n$ for some $n$, and $x\in A_n\cap C^m=B^m_n$ for each $m$.  So $x\in B_n$.  (The reverse inclusion is trivial)

Comment: Its very clear now,thank you!